# Filtering with radio inputs, displaying an all array values on render and having 'all' as an option

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm filtering my app with tags. Each tag is a radio input with a label. It successfully filters data that includes the tag selected.

My goal however is that on first render all data is displayed with an added 'All' radio button.

Heres my code so far

```
const [currentTag, setCurrentTag] = useState('');

  const filteredByTag = workouts.filter(workout =>
    workout.tags.filter(tag => tag).includes(currentTag)
  );

<div>
 <ul>
            {tags.map(tag => {
              return (
                <label
                  key={tag}
                  htmlFor={`filter-${tag}`}
                >
                  <span>{tag}</span>
                  <input
                    type='radio'
                    name='tag'
                    id={`filter-${tag}`}
                    value={tag}
                    checked={tag === currentTag}
                    onChange={e => setCurrentTag(e.target.value)}
                  />
                </label>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </div>
        <ul>
          {filteredByTag.map(workout => (
            <Workout
              key={workout.name}
              name={workout.name}
              description={workout.description}
              tags={workout.tags}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
```

The code above at the top includes my tags array `['back', 'biceps', 'chest]` mapped as radio inputs.
Code at the bottom display the workouts that contain the same tag as the value in `currentTag`

To clarify. So far only workouts are shown once a radio button has been clicked. What I want is for on render all workouts are shown with an additional 'All' radio input. So users can filter but then click 'All' to display all workouts.

Sorry if bad question, don't know where to start with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have an `all` option in the tags array. Have the `useState` default value as 'all'. Have a ternary and do filter only when currentTag is not `all` (i.e. do filtering only with user selected values)

```js
  const [currentTag, setCurrentTag] = useState('all');
...
  const filteredByTag = currentTag === 'all' ? workouts :  workouts.filter(workout =>
    workout.tags.includes(currentTag)
  );
```

In JSX, while mapping, include `all` as well.

```js
         <ul>
            {tags.concat('all').map(tag => {
              return (
                <label
...
```